# Как вывести в текстовый файл всё, что есть в консоли?

Tags: c++, файлы, c++builder, текстовые-файлы

Данные некорректно записываются в файл. Слово `test` нормально записалось, а вот цифры в виде квадратиков и других символов. Я хочу, чтобы в файл записывалось все, что есть в консоли, но не знаю как сделать, не получается.
На скриншоте видно, как отображаются данные :

[image: Скриншот]

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
using namespace std;
FILE *Ft;
struct stydents
{
    char    fio[40];
    int     dat[3];
    int     nomGr;
    int     fiz;
    int     mat;
    int     inf;
    int     chim;
} ;

void add()
{
    stydents w;
    FILE *bks;
    bks = fopen("D:/Library.txt", "a");
    char ch;
        do {

            cout << "\nФ.И.О. студента:         ";cin >> w.fio;
            cout << "Год рождения (дд.мм.гггг через пробел):  ";
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                cin >> w.dat[i];
            }
            cout << "Номер группы:              "; cin  >> w.nomGr;
            cout << "Оценка по физике:          "; cin >> w.fiz;
            cout << "Оценка по математике:      "; cin >> w.mat;
            cout << "Оценка по информатике:     "; cin >> w.inf;
            cout << "Оценка по химии:           "; cin >> w.chim;

            fwrite(&w, sizeof(stydents), 1, bks);
            cout << "\nХотите добавить еще? (y/n): ";
            cin >> ch;
        } while (ch != 'n');
    fclose(bks);
}


void list_list()
{
    stydents w;
    FILE *bks;

    bks = fopen("D:/Library.txt", "r");
    cout << "\n------------Список студентов--------------\n";
    while (fread(&w, sizeof(stydents), 1, bks))
    {
        cout << "\nФ.И.О. студента:          " << w.fio;
        cout << "\nГод рождения:               ";
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if (i == 1 || i == 2)
            {
                cout << ".";
            }
            cout << w.dat[i];
        }
        cout << "\nНомер группы:             " << w.nomGr;
        cout << "\nОценка по физике:         " << w.fiz;
        cout << "\nОценка по математике:     " << w.mat;
        cout << "\nОценка по информатике:    " << w.inf;
        cout << "\nОценка по химии:          " << w.chim;
        cout << "\nСредний балл:             " << static_cast<double>((w.chim + w.fiz + w.inf + w.mat) / 4.0);
        cout << endl;
    }
    fclose(bks);
}

void sTitle()
{
    stydents w;
    FILE *bks;

    bks = fopen("Library.txt", "r");
    int NomGr;
    cout << "\n" << "Введите номер интересующей вас группы: ";
    cin >> NomGr;
    cout << "\nРезультат поиска: ";
}

int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);


    int kod, kod_edit, edit_number;
    Ft = fopen("D:/result.txt", "w");
    while(1){
        puts("\n1 - View\t2 - Add\t0 - Exit\n");
        puts("Input the code here: ");
        scanf("%d", &kod);
        switch(kod){
            case 0:
                fclose(Ft);
                return 0 ;
            case 1:
                 list_list() ;

                break;
            case 2:
                 add();
                break;

        }

    getch();

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`fwrite(&w, sizeof(stydents), 1, bks);` — вы записываете бинарный файл. Поскольку структура `stydents` — POD, никаких проблем, так вполне можно.

Естественно, если вы хотите читать такой файл как текстовый, вы не увидите "нормальный" текст. Например, `fio` будет всегда занимать 40 байт, даже если вы введете слово из 1 буквы (в скобках заметим, что `cin >> w.fio` читает **одно слово**, так что вводить отдельно имя, отчество и фамилию так не получится).

Число типа `int` тоже будет представлено в виде 4 байт, которые никак не будут выглядеть, как введенное значение. Например, число 1633771873 записывается как 4 байта 0x61, так что в текстовом редакторе вы увидите не 1633771873, а строку `aaaa`...

Так что все нормально, просто несоответствие представлений.

Comment: а есть ли вариант записывать и в бинарный и в текстовый? Либо только в текстовый с хорошим форматированием

Comment: Мне нужно результат добавления студентов записать в тектовый файл

Comment: Только по отдельности. Либо — либо. Или писать программу, которая читает бинарные данные, а выводит текстовые — **что вы и сделали** :)

Comment: "*Мне нужно результат добавления студентов записать в тектовый файл*" — тогда пишите текстовый файл, функция `fprintf` вам в помощь, так сказать...

Comment: т.е. на вывод каждой строки писать fprintf ? или есть какой-то другой механизм?

Comment: Можете вызвать один раз — со сложной форматной строкой...